# Fatal error: Class 'PagesController' not found in

Tags: cakephp, import, controller, fatal-error

i m using cake for some time, and now i have a slightly modified pages controller, i want to use it in my default.ctp, i import it with

```
App::uses('PagesController', 'Controller');
```

or

```
App::import('Controller', 'Pages');
```

both work on my localhost xampp, neither on openshift web server.
whatever i do, i get the fatal error, class not found. been googling this problem for 2 hours, and feel like i m hitting the wall here. please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid these calls and use the CakePHP conventions. The difference between your local XAMPP copy and the OpenShift copy is probably due to running different versions of CakePHP, but this won't matter if you follow conventions.

It's best practice to put everything using the PagesController in the foler app/View/Pages. That way CakePHP handles all the imports, requires, routing, etc. Other than that, remember that the application path in OpenShift is /php/app/ (as opposed to the XAMPP /app/). I guess that could cause problems if you have custom controllers. Hope this helps!

Edit: I just realized that by default.ctp, you mean the layout file. I personally don't like calling controllers in the layout. I prefer to use the elements or helpers for this. Also, the PagesController isn't actually meant for being included in a site-wide layout. It's just meant for the files in your /app/View/Pages folder.

Comment: it works here, and i want it on every page, so basically i have to add it to layout anyway :|

Comment: As a follow-up, check out the helpers docs to see if this can possibly handle the logic you need. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, i used requestAction instead, and this works. :)
to solve similar issue, use lets say $pages = $this->requestAction('pages/');

then 'foreach' the $pages array whenever u need.
IMPORTANT! in your controller's function that creates the page(in this case controller pagesController and function 'index' ) dont forget to RETURN the $pages object u compose, and not just 'set' it as usually done. 
:)